# Prayers to Lord Shiva for daily meditation

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam, puja

I have a lady friend whom I have advised to meditate to Lord Shiva for 15-30 minutes daily. She is not practicing any formal sadhana and have some worldly desires that she tries to achieve by turning to western style "how to become successful-teachers" that demand a lot of money for their "teachings".

So, I thought why not advice her go to the Lord directly and try to appease Him in order to achieve her desires. Her desires are the usual, get rich and materially happy etc.

Any suggestions? Some nice prayers would be good and maybe advice on a short puja, she could try to get a murti of the Lord and make a simple offering daily.

I am a vaisnava myself but she is not very attracted to the path of renunciation.

Comment: initially itsvery difficult to meditate on God when mind is steeped in desires. She may sit in meditation as you prescribed, but her thoughts will naturally go towards: "Oh no, my husband is doing X today, my son/daughter is doing Y today, etc." Then within no time, she will lose interest and quit meditation. Sustained practice is key to achieve in meditation because results are not apparent immediately unlike other disciplines. Best formula (just opinion) = Meditation + Devotional Singing (Bhakti) + Charity (Karma) + Self-inquiry (Jnana) these form the four wheels of vehicle Sadhana

Comment: Thank you, Sai. I agree with you. Still a small endeavour is better than none :) Any guidance on sanskrit prayers directly addressing Lord Shiva would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes too believe that a small endeavour is better than none. suggestion is basically that in addition to meditation one can do singing/chanting + charity/service + self-inquiry/reflection. As for sanskrit prayers directly addressing Lord Shiva one can think of the Mrutyamjaya mantra which is as follows. oṁ tryambakaṁ yajāmahe sugandhiṁ puṣṭi-vardhanam ǀ
urvārukam-iva bandhanān mṛtyormukṣīya māmṛtāt ǁ Also one can chant the Rudram :) All d best Sir. Really admire your unbiased and open-minded attitude :)

Comment: Thank you Sai, with your help I found http://www.saivism.net/prayers/index.asp, that will keep her busy for this life time. Namaste.

Answer (score 4):

### Shiva deity of Moskha(Liberation) and Death - Ultimate(Main) GOD(Ishwara/Allah)

There is no other way to fulfil worldly desires unless she visits Shiva Lingam everyday.

There is one Shiva Lingam in Gujarat, which is known as `"Kuber Bhandari"`, This shiva lingam is known for fulfilling money or financial issues of people. Devotees visit this Great Jyotiswaroop Shiva lingam with true faith, they request Lord to fulfill them with money. It is a strong belief of devotees that `"Kuber Bhandari"` is master/owner of all money on earth. So they will be granted some money to be rich in materialized world.

Conclusion is that, one does not need to do meditation to be rich. **Happy people are happy rich/poor.** One must understand that even after being rich, one is only in charge of whatever they have. Having "Moha" is not good. But one if with true faith, requests GOD without "Moha", wishes are always fulfilled.

Better is let her go with western style meditation. She does not need GOD, she needs money only. So it is best to give her freedom whatever she feels is right. Meditation has nothing to do with materialized things. Meditation is for soul's peace, not for body.

If she choose to be with Hindu `Sadhana`,

Prayers are Om Namah Shivaya Dhun, by sitting exactly in front of Shiva Lingam, sitting should be comfortable enough. Because one needs to forget body while meditation. 
Other prayers are,

1. Shiva 1000 names (Shiva Sahstra Namavali),
2. Vishnu Sahastra Namavali and
3. Gayatri Mantra Dhun.
4. Shiva mahimna strotra
5. Om namah shivay dhun

All of them are available on You Tube. Download or play them when you sit in meditation, if you feel it is good to your heart.

Sadhana requires concentration, any music that increase your concentration is good while meditation BUT **DO NOT GIVE ATTENTION TO MUSIC WHILE MEDITATION.**

> The most effective in daily meditation according to me is "Om Namah Shivaya Dhun".

**Disclaimer:** *This prayers are chosen by me, they are not standardized ones. One can choose what one's heart feels good. This is my personal opinion based answer just to help questioner.*

### Prayer to GODDESS महालक्ष्मि

One can also seek money and get fulfillment by praying or chanting GODDESS महालक्ष्मि prayers.

[महालक्ष्मि अष्टकं](http://greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_lakshmi-mahalakshmi_ashtakam.php)  Verse 10

> एककाले पठेन्नित्यं महापापविनाशनम् ।
>   द्विकालं यः पठेन्नित्यं धनधान्यसमन्वितः ॥१०॥

10.1: Reciting this Once Every Day will Destroy Great Sins,
10.2: Reciting this Twice Every Day will bestow one with Wealth and Foodgrains.

So if you chant this prayer 2 times, morning and evening, it is written over here that you will be granted with wealth.

This one was important for your friend. Ask her to chant this prayer at morning and evening, 2 times a day. And check her status whether she gets wealth or not.

### Shani Chalisa

In shani chalisa, it says if you do this prayer on Saturday, "Lakshmi Gruh Ave" means money comes to your door.

### Fire Pray

If you perform fire rituals, it is given in Vedas that one will have money issues solved.

Comment: If I ask Shankaracharya of Jagannathapuri, as he is in my contact and whatever he tells, will it be authenticated and accepted on this site?

Comment: please make sure you secure his permission before doing that. That's because Acharyas usually give specific teachings to specific people. What is instructed to you may not be needed for everyone. It also may be dangerous to put in public what he intends to give only for you. Thanks. :):)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Yes, I think personal communication with someone like the Shankaracharya of Puri would definitely be acceptable on this site.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Were you able to talk to the Shankaracharya of Puri?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan No, actually he left before I can meet him. But I will meet him again in next meeting, at that time I will ask him for Lord Shiva Prayers. Sorry.  So he will inform me when he will again visit Gujarat, and I will go and meet him.

Answer (score 1):

Meditating on Shiva for the attainment of worldly desires is pointless. Shiva is only attracted to pure love. He is not attracted to beggars - and that is what people are that pray to God for the fulfillment of worldly desires. He is not an accountant, you can't chant his name so many times and expect x in return. Do you think that God is a fool? He is only attracted to those that have yearning for Him alone. Her chanting and meditating is so much water thrown on a frying pan.

If she wants worldly desires fulfilled, she should pray and do puja to a deva as directed by a Brahmin, or ask a Brahmin for some mantras. But those who do so attain that as described in the Gita (2. 42-44).

Comment: Shiva is anti-attraction. Shiva is GOD himself. How can you say Shiva is attracted to anything? Everything is GOD's property. And yes of course GOD gives money if devotee ask. Don't you think you should consider case of Kubera?

Comment: Read the Gita verses I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Tell her that chanting mantras for the sake of attaining such mundane world desires is pointless.

If she wants to earn money, given that she is a woman, she can rely on the oldest profession in the world.

Anyway, if she wants to chant on Lord Shiva for evolving, ask her to chant [Lingashtakam](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_shiva-lingashtakam.php) to get started.

More Stotras on Lord Shiva are available [here](http://www.greenmesg.org/bharatavarsha/stotras/shiva_stotras.php).

In general, I have found the website [greenmesg.org](http://www.greenmesg.org/) to be very useful for other Stotras as well.

Answer (score 0):

Meditation leads to **moksha** but on what one should meditate , many meditate on lord **shiva** which is indeed useful.
but the question arises that on what **Adiyogi**(Shiva) meditates on, 
he meditates on himself considering him to be all that is truth, this is true yoga.
because yoga means **unification**,so one should always consider that he is everything which is truth this way we unify ourselves to the **satya**.
Therefore one should meditate on oneself reciting

> **SHIVOHAM**

(meaning, I am Shiva) to achieve samadhi the ultimate goal of yoga.